# Merge Replication and the Performance Impact on the controller SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication, database-performance, merge-replication

A third party vender implemented a solution that makes use of merge replication on our main SQL server. This server also hosts our SAP B1 db. Since the implementation of the solution our users have been experiencing performance issues on SAP B1. Is there a way where I can view how much processing and memory the merge replication is using from the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late now but we had a similar issue and in the end had to move the Merge Replication solution to its own hardware.

The rest of the systems started working perfectly again after that... though the Merge Replication application is still a disaster